# Data Access Layer DatabaseContext Do I have to map all relationships for my classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relational-database, entity-relationship

In my `OnModelCreating` method do I have to map every table's relationship like i did with my `Tickets` and `Administrator` class?

I read this article and the writer only did one of the relationships but not all of it. If you scroll down in the link I've provided to "**Customize the Data Model by adding Code to the Database Context**" you will see what I'm talking about.

Source: [Click Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

IssueContext.cs

```
public class IssueContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Administrators).WithMany(i => i.Tickets)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("TicketID")
                    .MapRightKey("AdministratorID")
                    .ToTable("Adminstrators on Tickets"));

            }
    }
```

My Entity Diagram
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my OnModelCreating method do I have to map every table's relationship like i did with my Tickets and Administrator class?

EF Code First came with some default conventions like the one you already disable by calling this line of code:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Those conventions help EF Code First to know:

- which entity belong to which table,
- who is the primary key,
- what is the relationship between your entities and create those relationship into your database tables
- ....

If you follow the conventions, you will not need to write a connfiguration by using fluent API or data annotation attributes.

The following configuration you worte:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Administrators).WithMany(i => i.Tickets)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("TicketID")
            .MapRightKey("AdministratorID")
            .ToTable("Adminstrators on Tickets"));
```

is useful because if you let EF to generate the join table between `Ticket` and `Administrator` you will have some issue to know which is the left key and which is the right key. You also tell EF to generate `TicketID` and `AdministratorID` as column name  instead of `Ticket_ID` and `Administrator_ID` which are the default names it will use on the join table.

To answer to your question. **No you don't need to add mappings for all entities.** Use conventions as much as possible and then use fluent configuration or data annotation attributes to tweak and refine some columns, tables etc like you do with your join table.

**Side note:** `Adminstrators on Tickets` is not a good table name for a table just use `AdministratorsTickets`

Comment: Thank you so much for putting the effort to explain this to me in detail. Really appreciated it! Now thanks to you I fully understand why he didn't map everything.